# Dynamically varying number of nested for loops

Tags: java

I'm learning Java - came across this problem:

> Write a program that rolls n dice, where the dice are all d-sided. By
>   using simulation, report an approximate value for the probability of
>   rolling a total of x or more, using the dice, where x, n and d are all
>   given as inputs. For example, if n = 2, d = 6 and x = 7, the program
>   should report 58.3% probability (approximately).

This is what I came up with

```
public class Main {

    public double calcProbability(int n, int d, int x){
        int[] sums = new int[(int)Math.pow(d, n)]; //Creates an array of max size needed
        int counter = 0;    
        int occurrences = 0; //No. of times that the number being added to the array is greater than d
        for(int i=1;i<=d;i++){
            for(int j=1;j<=d;j++){
                if((i+j)>=x){
                    occurrences++;
                }
                sums[counter]=(i+j);
                counter++;
            }
        }
        return (double)occurrences/Math.pow(d, n); //Returning probability
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Main().calcProbability(2, 6, 7));
    }

}
```

It works fine for n=2 (I think), since I'm using two nested for loops. But I'm having trouble figuring out how to vary the number of for loops with n (this will allow me to add all the possible totals to the array - the rest of the code should work fine as is).

Would appreciate some guidance.

---

Thanks everybody, after taking into account everyone's contribution, here's the revised method:

```
public double calcProbability(int n, int d, int x){
        Random random = new Random(); //Random numbers simulate dice rolling
        int occurrences = 0; //No. of times that the number is greater than d
        for(int i=0;i<100000;i++)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                sum+=random.nextInt(d)+1;
            }
            if(sum>=x) {
                occurrences++;
            }

        }
            return (double)occurrences/100000; //Will be an approximation
    }
```

It was pointless storing those numbers then counting the number of occurrences - rather just count the occurrence when it takes place and move on.

Comment: You can calculate the exact change without a simulation.

Comment: Adding to @PeterLawrey: you **cannot** compute the probability with simulation. You have to come up with a formula and solve that formula for the given input

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the problem even for the given inputs. You are not "rolling dices", as I understand you should use a random number generator. The idea is not to compute the probabilistic value (could be done by hand), but to simulate dice rolling and verify that it converges to some value.

Comment: It appears that this is a programming assignment, and not a math assignment. The text says "By using simulation".

Comment: @luk2302 you can simulate every possible roll combination, however with random rolls you can get an approximate probability but it has a small chance of being completely wrong.

Comment: By some stats law, you can control that this change tends to 0, no?

Comment: @ak1652 Have you solved this problem? I see that you already added an edited solution into your question.  If it is still unsolved, I can provide a programming solution.

Comment: Yes, I have solved it. Thanks!

Comment: @ak1652 You can accept one of the solution here (including your own) then (to indicate this question as solved).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everybody, after taking into account everyone's contribution, here's the revised method:

```
public double calcProbability(int n, int d, int x){
        Random random = new Random(); //Random numbers simulate dice rolling
        int occurrences = 0; //No. of times that the number is greater than d
        for(int i=0;i<100000;i++)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                sum+=random.nextInt(d)+1;
            }
            if(sum>=x) {
                occurrences++;
            }

        }
            return (double)occurrences/100000; //Will be an approximation
    }
```

It was pointless storing those numbers then counting the number of occurrences - rather just count the occurrence when it takes place and move on

Answer (score 4):

For the purpose of dynamic loops, the answer is as follows. However, skip to second paragraph for a more recommended way of doing this. The way to get dynamic loops is with recursion. I can elaborate more if you want, but on a high level, what you have is a parameter that specifies the nth dice and decrements, and when it reaches the 0th dice, then the recursion ends. You'll have to change quite a bit with the variables, and move them into parameters or globals so you can keep updating them with the function.

In the case of this problem, I would approach it quite differently. Create a function called Roll that takes two parameters: a range of the the dice values and the amount of dice to roll. I'll leave the specifics of the function of to you, but it involves generating random numbers a certain amount of times. Since the problem requires simulation, call this Roll function some high number of times, and then use an array to keep track of the answers that come out. At that point, do the division and percentages to get a good approximation.

Comment: Why use recursion for this problem? There is no need for "dynamic number of loops" here...

Comment: I was referring more to the dynamic amount of loops, rather than the problem here

Comment: I agree with @Jean-BaptisteYunès this actually does not answer the question at all. You are absolutely correct regarding loops vs. recursion but this problem cannot be solved using either by actually rolling dices - OP has to do the math behind it.

Comment: The problem says simulation though..it's possible that the intent is actual simulation, in which case dynamic loops are still an unfortunate way to do it. Will update

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should just iterate over possible results of dice rolling in one loop.

A result is a integer array of size `n` with value all in *[1, d]*.

And your code will be:

```
int occurrences = 0;
int count = 0;
Result result = new Result(n, 1); // n times 1.
while(result != null)
{
    if (result.Sum >= x) occurrences++;
    count++;

    GetNextResult(result);
}

double probability = occurrences / (double) count;
```

Where `GetNextResult` return the next possible result or `null` if the input is `[d, d, ..., d]`.

Of course you have to code `Result` class correctly.